# The names in this table are / is a list of attendances

Tags: multiplicity

Which sounds natural for you, native speakers of English?

1. The names in this table are a list of attendances.
2. The names in this table is a list of attendances.

Please answer with your choice. Also, add some reason if possible.

Comment: *Attendances?* More likely, ***attendees*** (those people who attended).

Comment: I would not use _names_ at all. The word is superfluous here. And, like @FumbleFingers, I would use _attendees_, never _attendances_. I would write _This table is a list of attendees_. Or even _This table lists attendees_.

Comment: Neither sounds natural. As pointed out, this is local idiom, with _names in this table_ and _list of attendances_ very odd phrases from an American standpoint. Tables and lists are pretty much the same thing, when they contain names, anyway, so I wouldn't mention the names at all, except that I'm not sure what _attendances_ means. 'Instances of students' attendance at lectures', with missing dates highlighted, perhaps? _Attendances_ = _attendees_, as suggested? Maybe; _attendees_ is an American (and perhaps UK; I don't know) neologism; _attendances_ could be the neologism somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a) The names in this table are a list of attendances.

Correct. The subject is the noun "names", which is plural; its verb ("are") must agree with it in number.

> b) The names in this table is a list of attendances.

Incorrect. The subject is plural and cannot be paired with a singular noun.

Answer (score 1):

The table (singular) is a list. The names (plural, and they happen to be in a table) are a list.

Comment: I agree. It is a similar structure to "The names on this piece of paper are written in pencil". However the names are presented and no matter what they form they are plural so "The names ... are..." is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The *table* is a *list* of attendees.
The *names* are the *people* who attended (or are the attendees).